# How to run iostat/vmstat/top/sar till all the background processes are completed?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ubuntu-12.04, benchmarking

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start.sh
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]] ; then
    echo 'Usage :<./Start N# >'
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $1 -ge 1 ]] ; then
    for (( c=1; c<=$1; c++ ))
    do
        virsh start VM$c
        /usr/bin/time -f "%E" ./test-online.sh VM$c &
    done
else
    echo 'Give some positive number !!!'
fi
/usr/bin/iostat -x 1 > result.txt
```

In the above script I am measuring the time for VM bootup, which is written in the test-online.sh script. I want to stop /usr/bin/iostat -x 1 > result.txt command when every background process(test-online.sh) finishes.

Start.sh will wait for background processes if we add "wait" command instead of "/usr/bin/iostat -x 1 > result.txt". But now I am confused, How to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want `iostat` to run only once, after all the background jobs have finished?

Comment: yes, but its continuous ,so after starting it will run infinitely. We can give number of time to run iostat, but in my case I want to run this until all the background processes are over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start.sh
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]] ; then
    echo 'Usage :<./Start N# >'
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $1 -ge 1 ]] ; then
    for (( c=1; c<=$1; c++ ))
    do
        virsh start VM$c
        /usr/bin/time -f "%E" ./test-online.sh VM$c &
    done
else
    echo 'Give some positive number !!!'
fi
./kill_script.sh &
/usr/bin/sar -urdp 1 > result.txt
```

In the first script we are starting lots of background processes and after that we are calling kill_script.sh before iostart/sar/vmstat etc. and In the kill_script.sh we are checking if there is any child process, named test-online.sh, of process Start.sh. If there is no process then go out of the loop and kill the iostat/vmstat/sar etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
#kill_script.sh
pid=`pgrep -o -x Start.sh`
out="a"
while true
do
    out=`ps --ppid $pid | grep time`
    sleep 1 
    echo $out
    if [ -z "$out" ]; 
    then 
        break;
    fi
done
kill $(pidof sar) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Here assumption is , we are the only one to use that command i.e iostat/vmstat/sar etc to get the system stats.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem once. Since I'm big Python fan, I implemented a module in python that does that: https://gist.github.com/myaut/38e5d7cb813ed0db379c

Here is small example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, subprocess
import time
import bench

from datetime import datetime

cmd = "sleep 40"
benchdir = '/var/tmp/mybench-%s/' % datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M')
print 'Destination is %s' % benchdir

stats = [bench.statcmd('date', [], 5, False),
        bench.statcmd('vmstat', ['5']),
        ]
bench.run_test(cmd, stats, 'sleep', benchdir)
```

Module also supports Python classes as statistics collector, but I omitted  it from example. This example runs `date` command once per 5 seconds and runs `vmstat` continously with `5` as argument. Output is written in `/var/tmp/mybench-DATE` directory.

Again, sorry for non-bash implementation. Hope that it helps.

Comment: Sir my question is something else and you are answering something else. I started some process in background and then I started taking stats, and I want to stop taking stats when all those background processes are over.

Comment: @Ankit, that's what my program does - it starts `sleep 40`, starts `vmstat` and periodically runs `date`. When `sleep 40` is finished it stops `vmstat`, writes all data to `/var/tmp/mybench-DATE` and exits

Comment: but in that sense also its deterministic and we can't be sure when all the background processes (almost 100 processes which checks if the VM is booted up or not )will be over.

Comment: @Ankit So you need run _multiple_ background processes and finish `*stat` tools when _all_ of them are finished?